# How to get video url using file_get_contents in php

Tags: php, preg-match, file-get-contents

Im trying to get video and poster from another site
Lets call it othersite.com

other site.com has this parameters:

```
<div class="player">
    <div id="l_player" class='l-player' >
        <noscript>
            <video style="width:100%; height:100%;"
               controls="controls"
               autobuffer="autobuffer"
               class="player-html5"
               preload="metadata"
               poster="http://othersite.com/img.jpg">
                <source src="http://othersite.com/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </noscript>
    </div>
```

with the below php I got the image from the opengraph tag but Im trying to get the mp4 url which I couldnt get yet

```
$Agent  = array('http' => array('user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0; en-us; GT-I9300 Build/IMM76D)'));
$String = file_get_contents('http://www.othersite.com/'. $video .'/', false, stream_context_create($Agent) );
preg_match("/<source src=\"(.*)\" controls type=\"video\/mp4\"/", $String, $VideoURL);
$VideoURL = $VideoURL[1];
$IMG = getstring($String,'<meta property="og:image" content="','"');
```

my php is getting the image only do you have any idea what Im doing wrong in preg_match and how to get the `http://othersite.com/video.mp4`

Comment: There is no `controls` in your source. You also shouldn't use regex to parse HTML/XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using Preg_Match in the following way. It's pretty simple and it works extremely well!

```
$source = file_get_contents("That Page");

preg_match("'<source src=\"(.*?)\" type=\"video/mp4\">'si", $source, $match);
if($match) echo "result=".$match[1];
```

This should do what you want it to.

After a recent comment, I felt that I should also add that The si modifiers are making this regex looser.

Comment: resolved FluxCoder you are great my friend I have from the morning with this as its ready will make this resolved thankyou verymuch.Do you have any advanced link to learn this logic?

Comment: Answers should have an explanation. The `si` modifiers are making this regex looser.

Comment: Not really, I would love to be able to help you in private, but I actually don't know how you'd do that, without adding me on skype: FluxCoder

Comment: @Gazi Regex logic or...? http://www.regular-expressions.info/ has a lot of info, https://regex101.com/ is good for testing a regex and seeing how/why it functions as it does. Here's your first regex https://regex101.com/r/aT0fW3/1 and as you can see with https://regex101.com/r/aT0fW3/2, just removing `controls` resolved the issue. I'd change your delimiter and quote usage. That will cut down on your escaping as well.

Comment: @Gazi that was just from knowledge & past experience.